# How to use batch in hook_uninstall?

Tags: 7, batch-operations, installation

I have big data in `hook_uninstall()`. How to handle this data? Can I use batch in `hook_uninstall()`?

Comment: Which version of Drupal are you using? Can you clarify what do you mean by "big data", and what do you want to do with it in `hook_uninstall()`?

Comment: I'm sorry. I use Drupal 7. Big data - very, very many files. For each file I call file_unmanaged_delete, file_unmanaged_copy, file_usage_delete. At the moment I have php_error max_execution_time.

Comment: Got it; makes more sense now, for a moment I thought you just wanted to dump big tables from the database :) will post if I find some more time today.

Comment: If it's urgent for you, check out the Content Access module. I think it invokes rebuilding node access permissions batch process upon uninstallation.

Comment: I check Content Access module. It's not use batch :(

Comment: After thinking about this and reading the [docs on `hook_uninstall()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_uninstall/7), it might be better to create a page where you will perform the batch process, and only then uninstall the module manually. That way you can use full batch API. See [Examples](https://www.drupal.org/project/examples) bundle - it contains an example for using Batch API as well. Let me know if this works.

Comment: Yes, of course, I can do it, but I want to use batch in unistalling. Examples module is not suitable for my task.

Comment: Got it; for now I'm out of ideas - would need to really dig into the code and perform some tests. The thing is that `hook_uninstall()` is invoked right before your module is disabled, so having a batch in between would somehow need to pause that, process the batch and then resume uninstallation. I suggest searching for a contrib module that would need to do the same, and seeing how did they overcome the problem. Good luck!